# How to catch errors involving too many arguments in python?

Tags: python

I’m trying to prepare code that catches errors in commands typed in by the user and returns a suggestion.

For example, if I type in turnleft(2,1) and the actual command is turnLeft(2,1), the program would return: “Oh no! You typed: turnleft(2,1). Did you mean to type turnLeft?”

So far the program catches all the errors I need it to if the error is before the parenthese. But now I’m trying to write code that would catch too many arguments. For example turnLeft(3,2,1) would return, “Looks like you’ve entered too many arguments in your function. Try turnLeft(2,1).

How would I do this?

At the moment the program simply returns: “Oh no! You typed: turnLeft(3,2,1). Did you mean turnLeft?” But I want it to return a message saying that there were too many arguments. How would I catch errors inside the parentheses instead of errors outside the parentheses?

So far this is the code I have:

```
from Myro import *
import difflib
import __builtin__
errorBox = None

variableList = []
for key in calico.manager.scope.GetVariableNames():
    variableList.append(key)
for key, value in __builtins__.iteritems():
    variableList.append(key)

def formatError(error, text):

    bestMatches = difflib.get_close_matches(text, variableList, 1)
    beforeParn = text[0:text.find("(")]
    afterParn = text[text.find("("):text.find(")")]

    print ("\nOh no! You typed:")
    print ("\n\t", text)
    print ("\nDid you mean:")

    if bestMatches:
        print ("\n\t", bestMatches)

    if not bestMatches:
        bestMatchesParn = difflib.get_close_matches(beforeParn, variableList)
        if bestMatchesParn:
            print ("\n\t", bestMatchesParn)
        if not bestMatchesParn:
            print ("\n\tCommand not found.")

calico.manager["python"].engine.OnErrorCallback = formatError
```

Comment: Read About handling exceptions, raising exceptions, and user defined exceptions in the [Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#exceptions).

Comment: I guess what i'm asking is how to catch errors in the parameters of an argument.

Comment: You Could probably do it with a decorator. I just searched for validating parameters with a decorator and got a lot of hits.  You Could probably easily adapt this one - https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Easy_Dump_of_Function_Arguments